# Función AJAX segura en Django

Tags: python, sql, ajax, python-3.x, django

tengo la siguiente funcion AJAX que me retorna los datos del profesional con el id que le paso por GET

```
$.get('/get_professional_info/', {idProfessional: id}, function(data){
        var professional = JSON.parse(data)[0].fields;
        # Trabajo con el profesional
});
```

Después declaro en my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^get_professional_info/$', get_professional_info),
    # ...
]
```

Y por último mi función en views.py:

```
def get_professional_info(request):
    idPro = request.GET['idProfessional']
    profesional = Profesional.objects.filter(id_profesional = int(idPro))
    # Lo formateo en JSON
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type = "application/json")
```

Mi duda es como hago para hacer esta función segura, ya sea ocultandola o bloqueandola solo para que sea accesible desde mi función de javascript. Ya que si voy a la dirección desde el navegador enviando la información(ejemplo: www.genarito.com/idProfessional=1) me arroja todo en pantalla, dejando el escenario propicio para SQL injections de todo tipo.
Así se ve desde la URL:

[image: Se puede acceder a todo desde el navegador]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrarlo en alguna carpeta static de tu proyecto
Hacer referencia al script en tu plantilla html de la siguiente manera: ​
Listo! Ahora puedes hacer tus peticiones sin tener que preocuparte en el token :)

```
  /**
     * Este script de javascript permite trabajar transparentemente solicitudes que requieren 
     * protección del token CSRF por medio de AJAX JQUERY.
     * Esto te permitirá hacer solcitudes a web Services de Django por medio de AJAX Jquery.
     * Para utilizarlo basta con integrar el archivo DjangoAjax.js en tu directorio de JS  y hacer referencia a él en tus templates 
     * que requieren del uso de AJAX por POST o algún otro que requiera el token CSRF.
     * Este script está basado en la documentación oficial de Django https://docs.djangoproject.com
     */

    $(function(){
        //Obtenemos la información de csfrtoken que se almacena por cookies en el cliente
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

        //Agregamos en la configuración de la funcion $.ajax de Jquery lo siguiente:
        $.ajaxSetup({
                        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
                                // Send the token to same-origin, relative URLs only.
                                // Send the token only if the method warrants CSRF protection
                                // Using the CSRFToken value acquired earlier
                                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                            }
                        }
        });

    function sameOrigin(url) {
        // test that a given url is a same-origin URL
        // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
        var host = document.location.host; // host + port
        var protocol = document.location.protocol;
        var sr_origin = '//' + host;
        var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
        // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
        return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
            (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
            // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
            !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
    }

    // usando jQuery
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }


        function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
            // estos métodos no requieren CSRF
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
        }
    });
```

El ejemplo de consulta seria

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'mi_url',
    type: "POST",
    data: {'variable': value},
    success: function (response) {
       //lo que haces si es exitoso
    }

});
```

Y tu archivo para que sea solo por consultas ajax para una api-rest

```
def ajax_test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "This is ajax"
    else:
        message = "Not ajax"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```